# SQLDelight: how to create table dynamically?

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform, sqldelight

I saw examples where we can create a table with fixed name using `sq` file like that

```
CREATE TABLE hockeyPlayer (
  player_number INTEGER NOT NULL,
  full_name TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

I need to create tables with arbitrary names at runtime, how could I achieve this?

**UPD**

It seems I have to execute all queries manually in this case (like it's done in generated classes)

```
val driver = DatabaseDriverFactory().createDriver(databaseName)
val tableName = "table2"
driver.execute(null, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $tableName (player_number INTEGER NOT NULL, full_name TEXT NOT NULL", 0, null)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of manual/dynamic table creation & operations

```
    fun test(databaseName: String, key: String?) {
        val driver = DatabaseDriverFactory().createDriver(databaseName, key)
        val tableName = "table2"
        val identifier = 1

        // identifier here must be null to avoid SQLiteBindOrColumnIndexOutOfRangeException
        // in INSERT statements below
        driver.execute(null, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $tableName (player_number INTEGER NOT NULL, full_name TEXT NOT NULL)", 0, null)
        var cursor = driver.executeQuery(identifier, "SELECT * FROM $tableName", 0, null)

        if (!cursor.next()) {
            Napier.i("EMPTY TEST DB")
            driver.execute(identifier, "INSERT INTO $tableName (player_number, full_name) VALUES (?, ?)", 2) {
                // indices start here from 1
                bindLong(1, 1)
                bindString(2, "John")
            }
            driver.execute(identifier, "INSERT INTO $tableName (player_number, full_name) VALUES (?, ?)", 2) {
                bindLong(1, 2)
                bindString(2, "Mike")
            }
        }

        cursor = driver.executeQuery(identifier, "SELECT * FROM $tableName", 0, null)

        while (cursor.next()) {
            // indices start here from 0
            val number = cursor.getLong(0)
            val name = cursor.getString(1)
            Napier.i("Player #$number $name")
        }

    }
```